# How to insert a function call with <<<END notation?

Tags: php

I've a big file which echo a web page with "HERE DOCUMENT' notation:

```
echo <<<END
<div>
    <span>Some content</span>
    ...
</div>
END;
```

But of course it don't works.

I need to replace some content of this string by the resul of a static function:

```
echo <<<END
<div>
    <span>MOD_TRANSLATION::getContent('contentKey')</span>
    ...
</div>
END;
```

Is there a way to do it without closing/re opening HERE DOCUMENT's tags (like variable interpolation)?

Comment: hard to say... nowdoc? https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.nowdoc

Comment: `str_repalce()` If it is a unique placeholder?!

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't knew this page, very interesting... I [found](http://php.net/manual/fr/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) this syntaxe: `{${$object->getName()}}` Do you know if it works with static classes?

Comment: sorry, I don't, but someone had an answer with nowdoc, but deleted it. Ask the other guy below ;-) he's got upvotes on theirs.

Answer (score 3):

What you call the `<<<EOD` notation is called a [here document](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc). You can't use function calls in here documents. But you can use variables. Like this:

```
$date = date('H:i:s');

$string = <<<EOF
date = $date
EOF;

echo $string;
```